# Reduced label is displayed in c++ mfc application

Tags: c++, mfc

I develop some C++ MFC application. In my dialog box there is a progress bar and one label with constant text (cyrillic symbols).

On Windows 7,XP this text is displayed good but on Windows 8,10 it is displayed in reduced form.

Why?

This is on Windows 7:

[image]

And this is on Windows 8:

[image]

This is a source code of the class related to this Dialog Form.
*.cpp file:

```
// Progress.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LybidLoader.h"
#include "Progress.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"


// Progress dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(Progress, CDialogEx)

Progress::Progress(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialogEx(Progress::IDD, pParent)
{

}

Progress::~Progress()
{
}

void Progress::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_PROGRESS1, m_ProgressBar);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Progress, CDialogEx)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &Progress::OnBnClickedForceExit)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// Progress message handlers


BOOL Progress::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    ModifyStyle( WS_SYSMENU, 0);

    m_ProgressBar.SetMarquee(TRUE, 10);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
    // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}


void Progress::OnBnClickedForceExit()
{   
    if (::MessageBoxW(this->m_hWnd, (LPCWSTR)_T("Ви впевнені? Буде здійснено        аварійний вихід"), (LPCWSTR)_T("Підтвердіть дію"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION |         MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }           
}


BOOL Progress::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class

    if( pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN )
    {
        if(pMsg->wParam == VK_RETURN || pMsg->wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
        {
            return TRUE;                // Do not process further
        }
    }

    return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

And *.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include "afxcmn.h"


// Progress dialog

class Progress : public CDialogEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(Progress)

public:
    Progress(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~Progress();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_PROGRESSBAR };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    CProgressCtrl m_ProgressBar;



    afx_msg void OnBnClickedForceExit();
    virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);
};
```

And this is a portion of resources file:

```
IDD_PROGRESSBAR DIALOGEX 0, 0, 369, 105
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE |  WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Будь-ласка, зачекайте!"
FONT 8, "Microsoft Sans Serif", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "",IDC_PROGRESS1,"msctls_progress32",PBS_MARQUEE | WS_BORDER,7,47,355,14
    LTEXT           "Триває обмін даними з опціональною платою! НЕ ВИМИКАЙТЕ РАДІОСТАНЦІЮ",IDC_STATIC,25,19,267,8
    PUSHBUTTON      "Примусово завершити роботу",IDC_BUTTON1,101,84,118,14
END
```

Comment: You have not provided any details on how this dialog window is implemented. So it would be extremely hard to help you out without source code.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin I added new empty dialog box and put there progress bar item and one label. In properties of the label I set static text that should be displayed... In my implemetation there is only handler of button press... If needed I can show the source code of header file and cpp file of the class related to this dialog form.

Comment: @storojs72:  Source code would be good - preferably with extraneous detail removed (but check that the reduced version still has the problem).  Don't forget the relevant portion of the .rc file too.

Comment: @MartinBonner source code added

Answer (score 4):

Disregard the garbage characters in the following images, it's just a codepage issue.

The space you provide for the static text controls too small:

The first dialog is yours, modify it so that it looks like the second one.

[image]

Comment: After a couple increasing/decreasing of label' inscription finally last word appeared on Windows 8... Thank you, but I unfortunatelly I don't understand why this problem occured on Windows 8 - newer than 7...

Comment: From the screencopies you provided I suppose you are using a DPI of 125% on Windows 7 and 100% on Windows 8. (you can set these in Control panel, Display).On different DPI settings the space taken by text may vary. You always should provide enough space for text with some margin.

Comment: I think you should change the first line to "Disregard the garbage characters in the following images.  It's ..."  (At first I thought you were telling the OP that he had garbage characters in *his* images).

Answer (score 1):

It could be font DPI, or it could be fonts themselves.  It could be "Microsoft Sans Serif" maps to a different font.  I have worked enough localization to know that some fonts are not available on all systems.  I would think that "Microsoft Sans Serif" would probably be, but I have seen systems in the Far East where "Arial" was not on the system.

If I were you, I would change "Microsoft Sans Serif" to "MS Shell Dlg" in your dialog resource.  "MS Shell Dlg" is sort of a virtual font that maps roughly to the default GUI font.